# Sort an array of strings by "uniqueness"

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, set, edit-distance

I found the `Levenshtein` edit distance algorithm (via the `damerau-levenshtein` gem) and I think it suits my purpose well enough.

This code compares every element to every other element in the array, adding the result of each comparison to a set of hashes which will be sorted by the `:distance` key.

When this code is in use, *the data in the array is logs from java services*, so large edit distances show me which logs are most unique compared to the rest.

Input data is in this form:
`["Failed to process service event Error: 404 Not Found", "Failed to process service event Error: Resource not found in Storage service", "Throughput exceeded for table test-us-east-1-service-table."]`

```
def get_edit_distances(arr)
  if arr.empty?
    return []
  end
  if arr.length == 1
    return [arr[0]]
  end
  dl = DamerauLevenshtein
  results = Set.new
  i = 0 #array position
  while i < arr.length
    j = i + 1 #element to compare arr[i] against

    while j < arr.length
      results.add({message: arr[i], distance: dl.distance(arr[i], arr[j], 1, 256)})

      #This is to make sure we have every element in the final results
      if j+1 == arr.length 
        results.add({message: arr[j], distance: dl.distance(arr[0], arr[j], 1, 256)})
        break
      end

      j += 1 #increment 
    end
    i += 1
  end
  final_results = results.to_a
  #sort in descending order by distance
  final_results.sort! {|a,b| b[:distance] <=> a[:distance]}
  #remove duplicates of messages now that everything is sorted
  final_results.uniq! {|m| m[:message]}
  #return array of messages
  final_results.map {|r| r[:message]}
end
```

The output of this code is an array of the messages, ordered by uniqueness:
`["Throughput exceeded for table test-us-east-1-service-table.", "Failed to process service event Error: Resource not found in Storage service", "Failed to process service event Error: 404 Not Found"]`

For an array of `928` elements (normally there will be ~10,000,000), I got an output of `11801` elements (there were multiple edit distances for a single result, the `set` prevented duplicate messages for the same distance).

Benchmark results for the whole loop:

```
                    user      system     total       real
Edit Dist Loop:  62.260000   0.110000  62.370000 ( 62.456783)
```

**Question:** Is there a better way to create a sorted array/set of unique elements, ordered by uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your original problem correctly, "sorting an array of log messages by uniqueness";find the logs that have the rarest occurrence.

if that is the case, try this:

```
def sort_by_uniqueness(arr)
  h = {}
  arr.each do |entry|
    a[entry] = 0 unless a.key?(entry)
    a[entry] += 1 
  end
  a.sort_by { |k, v| v }.map(&:first)
end
```

Comment: I have revised my question so hopefully it is easier to read, I'm not sure what the code you provided does since there are some syntax errors in it. 
I believe: 


   `def sort_by_uniqueness(arr)
      a = {}
      arr.each do |entry|
        a[entry] = 0 unless a.key?(entry)
        a[entry] += 1 
      end
      a.sort_by { |k, v| v }.map(&:first)
    end`

is what you meant to submit, but the output is not any different from the input as far as I can see.